# How to get all product images in modal slider?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, product-images

```
<div class="pdp-media">
    <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $item->getProductUrl(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'thumbnail')->resize(500); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($item->getName()); ?>">
    </a>
</div>
```

Currently I am getting only one image of that product in my modal, but I want all of that product's images in modal as slider.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<?php foreach ($item->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image): ?>
    <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $item->getProductUrl(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize(500); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($image->getLabel()); ?>">
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```